# Matrix representation in a non-orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Suppose I have a matrix representation of an operator in the standard basis. If I change the basis to one with basis vectors $\{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$, which are not orthonormal, how do I now get a matrix representation in this basis?

Specifically, I have

$$A = \sum_{ij} A_{ij}e_ie_j^*,$$

where $e_i^*$ is the transpose conjugate of $e_i$. If I now express the $e_i$ as linear combinations of $u_i$, I get

$$A = \sum_{ij}A'_{ij}u_{i}u^*_{j}$$

How are the matrices with entries $A_{ij}$ and $A'_{ij}$ related? Is there an invertible change-of-basis matrix (the one that goes from the standard basis to the $u_i$ basis) that relates the two?

EDIT: Just to clarify what I mean, an example of $u_i$ is

$$u_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}, u_2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, u_3 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ i\end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$u^*_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, u^*_2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}, u^*_3 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & -i\end{pmatrix}$$

Sorry if my notation was not correct in the first version of this question.

Comment: Does $u_1^{*}$ mean the operator with $u_1^{*}(u_1) = 1; u_1^{*}(u_2) = 0; u_1^{*}(u_3) = 0$?

Comment: I meant that the $u_i$ are basis column vectors and $u_i^*$ are the transpose conjugate of $u_i$ (so row vectors). I have edited to clarify this. The relation in your comment does not hold since $u_i$ and $u_j$ are not necessarily orthogonal for $i\neq j$.

Comment: Thanks -- that's nice and clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U$ denote the matrix whose columns are $u_1,u_2,u_3$. The matrix $A'$ with entries $A_{ij}'$ is given by
$$
A' = U^{-1} A(U^{-1})^*.
$$
$U$ can be regarded as a change of basis matrix [for a bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#The_matrix_of_a_bilinear_form).

---

**Edit:** The indices in the question and in my answer are correct. With block-matrix multiplication, note that
$$
A = \sum_{ij}A_{ij}' u_iu_j^* = 
\pmatrix{u_1 & u_2 & u_3} 
\pmatrix{A_{11}' & A_{12}' & A_{13}'\\ A_{21}' & A_{22}' & A_{23}' \\ A_{31}' & A_{32}' & A_{33}'}\pmatrix{u_1^* \\ u_2^* \\ u_3^*}\\
= U A' U^*. 
$$

Comment: I think this might be wrong (because of an error by OP) --- OP has written $A'_{ij} u_i u_j^{*}$, i.e. has transposed the vector corresponding to the *second* index rather than the first. That introduced a "transpose" into my answer, which is otherwise the same as yours, of course.

Comment: @JohnHughes isn't it normal to transpose the vector corresponding to the second index? In physics, this would be expressing a matrix as a linear combination of ket-bras $\vert\cdot\rangle\langle\cdot\vert$. I'm basically trying to do exactly that.

Comment: It may be normal in some fields like physics -- it certainly is logically meaningful -- but I'd say that in the mathematics I've done, I think mostly in terms of matrices, and $a_{ij}$ denotes the $i$th row, $j$ column of the matrix. When we multiply a matrix by a column vector, we do so on the right, computing $a_{ij}v_j$. Oh...wait. I see now. You think of that as feeding "v" to the covector e_j^{*}, which extracts the $j$th entry of $v$. I tend to think of $v$ as already a  list of coordinates (wrt some basis). I stopped learning physics just before bra-key notation, so it's a mystery.

Comment: I was wrong to describe your expression as an "error", and should have described it as a choice that was unexpected (for me!). And now, looking back at my answer, I think *my* indices might be swapped...I'll need to review.

Comment: Fixed. Ben was right all along, and our answers now agree (note that his "prime" is on the left, mine is on the right, so he has an inverse that I do not have.).

Comment: @BenGrossmann sorry for the basic question but is this a more general version of the usual statement that $A$ and $A'$ are related by a similiarity transformation? If $\{u_i\}$ form an orthonormal basis, then $(U^{-1})^* = U$ and one has $A = UA' U^{-1}$ - am I right?

Comment: @yugioh It's not more general, just different. When the $u_i$ form an orthonormal basis, then the two notions of similarity are the same, but in general $UAU^{-1}$ comes from a similarity of transformations and $UAU^T$ comes from a similarity of bilinear forms.

Comment: Sorry, one more question: I did not think about bilinear forms when I asked the question. I wrote down a matrix $A$ - specifically, its "coordinates" with respect to the standard basis using a linear combination of ket bras. I then asked what those coordinates were in a new basis and got $A'$. Why exactly did I end up with a similarity of bilinear forms relationship between the coordinate matrices $A$ and $A'$ and not a similarity of linear transformations relationship?

Comment: @yugioh The question is this: if $A$ and $A'$ encode the same object, then what is that object? It is not true that they encode the same transformation up to a change of basis, but they do encode the same bilinear form. In particular, if we think of $U^{-1}x$ as the coordinate-vector of $x$ relative to the basis $\mathcal B = \{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$, then the fact that
$$
x^*A'y = (U^{-1}x)^*A(U^{-1}y)
$$
tells us that $A$ is the matrix of the bilinear form encoded by $A'$ relative to $\mathcal B$.

Answer (score 2):

There is some matrix $C$ such that $u_i = Ce_i$ (namely, a matrix whose columns are the coordinate vectors $u_1, u_2, u_3$). I'll write $c_{ij}$ for the entries of this matrix. That gives
$$
u_i = \sum_j c_{ji}e_j.
$$
(this was previously swapped...sigh.) For what comes later, I'm going to shift an index and write
$$
u_i = \sum_k c_{ki}e_k.
$$

Note that
$$
u_j^{*} = e_j^{*} C^{*}.
$$
where $C^{*}$ denotes the conjugate-transpose of $C$, whose $ij$-entry is $\overline{c_{ji}}$; in coordinates, this means that
$$
u_j^{*} = \sum_\ell \overline{c}_{j\ell} e_{\ell}^{*}.
$$

Now let's substitute for the $u$s in the expression:
\begin{align}
A 
&= \sum_{ij}A'_{ij}u_{i}u^*_{j} \\
&= \sum_{ij}A'_{ij}\left(c_{ki}e_k\right)\left(\overline{c}_{j \ell} e_\ell^{*})\right) \\
&= \sum_{ijk\ell }A'_{ij}c_{ki}  \overline{c_{j\ell}} e_k e_\ell^{*} \\
&= \sum_{ijk\ell }c_{ki}A'_{ij} \overline{c_{j \ell }} e_i e_j^{*} 
\end{align}
But we have another expression for $A$ already, and equating coefficients of $e_i e_j^{*}$ gives
$$
A_{ij} = \sum_{k\ell} c_{ki} A'_{ij} \overline{c_{j \ell }}
$$
In matrix terms, this says that
$$
A = C A' \overline{C}
$$
if I've got the indexes right.

Comment: Thank you - both answers were very helpful!